# Word for craving a drug

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When a person is addicted to something, lets say a drug, and they are deprived of it for too long, they start getting sick, have anxiety attacks and crave for it extremely and uncontrollably.

Is there a word in English for that exact condition?

Comment: Withdrawal is commonly used. In [drug] withdrawal, suffering from withdrawal, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone stops taking a drug they've developed a dependence on, they're said to exhibit (***drug***) ***[withdrawal symptoms](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/withdrawal-symptoms)***, collectively called [***withdrawal syndrome***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_syndrome) when they occur together (e.g., *alcohol withdrawal syndrome*).

Or shortened, as user Michael Harvey says in a comment, the addict is said to suffer from [***withdrawal***](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/withdrawal).

Answer (score 2):

'Withdrawal' is fine, but colloquially this is known as "going cold-turkey", whether the action is by choice or has been enforced in some way.

Comment: But mostly, going cold-turkey describes the act of stopping, not the condition or symptoms that he's going through, right?

Comment: @BellaSwan  No, quite the opposite - "Cold Turkey" actually comes from the physical goose-bumps etc that the addict suffers from, leaving their skin/bodies 'like a piece of cold turkey meat'